Ubuntu 24.04 printers: (where) did the "Additional printers settings" button disappear?
On Ubuntu 24.04, I cannot locate anymore the Additional printers settings button, that used to be at the bottom of the Settings -> Printer menu... did it disappear, or was put somewhere else? I could not find any documentation on that..
Thanks!
Left is the Printers menu on 20.04, right on 24.04... I can't see the button?
 

Aren't the additional printer settings now covered entirely by the wheel icon against each individual printer? The option you saw before was just an alternate view of the same option.

I don't think so, as I am trying to use that button precisely to add a new printer not on the list...

Isn't There an option on the top bar to Add Printer? see https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html.en

that's not the same unfortunately, that one will not allow you to printer such as LPD...

for Line Printer Daemon (LPD) you need to add CUPS to your system see this resource. After which you can then use the Add Printer option on the top bar and in the search box type in lpd and that will show CUPS-BRF-Printer to selct from.

Later versions of GNOME have removed the Additional Printer Settings menu option as it is a repetition of the options available using the wheel icon against an individual installed printer. However, the OP mentions that there seem to be two competing menus, one Activity -> Settings -> Printers and the other Activity -> Printerswhich might cause some confusion depending on version.
However, if your printer was not set up automatically, you can still add it using the printer panel settings.

Open the Activities overview and start typing Printers.
Click Printers.
Depending on your system, you may have to press Unlock in the top
right corner and type in your password when prompted.
Press the Add Printer… button.
In the pop-up window, select your new printer and press Add.

Ubuntu Reference Guide
If you are looking to install Line Printer Daemon (LPD) you need to add CUPS to your system see this resource. After which you can then use the Add Printer option on the top bar and in the search box type in lpd and that will show CUPS-BRF-Printer to select from.


excellent, thanks! I think the very tricky story here is that there is a Settings -> Printers menu with an add printers button that does not allow to add lpd (while it did before) and a printers menu directly accessible from Activity that has an Add button that allows to add lpd, right? Thanks!

If that addressed your issue, please consider accepting the answer by using the grey check mark under the votes which will help anyone else with the same or similar issue find a solution. Thanks a lot.

definitely, will do! I think it might be important to clarify the distinction between the Settings -> Printers and Printers, and emphasize you are talking about the latter? Seems to be a new distinction (wasn't there at least for 20.04) possible confusing "anyone else with the same or similar issue"? Thanks!

was that not covered sufficiently in the  opening paragraph of the answer well enough? Happy to add your concern to the answer if you think it will add clarification, of course. Let me know and thanks.

the fact that there seem to be two competing menus, one Activity -> Settings -> Printers and  the other Activity ->Printers? That's the most confusing part to me, that seems worth mentioning?

That's now been edited as per your helpful suggestion.

thanks a lot @graham for your contribution(s), much appreciated!
